# Is there a commonly-accepted/used notion of parametric statistical model equivalence?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, definition

To fix notation, let a set of possible data $X$ and a set of admissible parameter values $\Theta$ be given.  Let $\mathscr P(X)$ be the set of probability distributions on $X$.  A parametric statistical model over $X$ and $\Theta$ is a mapping $p:\Theta\to\mathscr P(X)$.  If $p$ is a statistical model over $X$ and $\Theta$, we use the notation $p(\cdot\,|\,\theta)$ for the distribution that $\theta$ is mapped to by $p$.

Let $p_1$ be a statistical model over $X$ and $\Theta_1$, and let $p_2$ be a statistical model over $X$ and $\Theta_2$.  I'm tempted to propose something like the following notions of equivalence for such models:

**Candidate 1.** $p_1$ and $p_2$ are *form-equivalent* provided they are equal up to reparameterization; there exists a bijection $f:\Theta_1\to\Theta_2$ for which $p_1(x\,|\,\theta_1) = p_2(x\,|\,f(\theta_1))$ for all $x\in X$ and $\theta_1\in\Theta_1$.

**Candidate 2.** Let $x^{(N)} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N)$ be a sequence of data (each $x_n\in X$).  Let $\hat\theta_1(x^{(N)})$ and $\hat\theta_2(x^{(N)})$ be parameter estimates computed by fitting models 1 and 2 to this sequence of data according to a procedure that assumes they are independently generated, namely generated by the distributions
\begin{align}
  p_1^{(N)}(x^{(N)}\,|\,\theta ) 
&= p_1(x_1\,|\,\theta)p_1(x_2\,|\,\theta)\cdots p_1(x_N\,|\theta) \\
  p_2^{(N)}(x^{(N)}\,|\,\theta ) 
&= p_2(x_1\,|\,\theta)p_2(x_2\,|\,\theta)\cdots p_2(x_N\,|\theta).
\end{align}
We say that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are *asymptotically inference-equivalent* provided they agree as closely as one desires given that they are fitted with enough data.  More precisely, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N_*>0$ such that if $N>N_*$ then
\begin{align}
  |p_1(x\,|\,\hat\theta(x^{(N)})) - p_2(x\,|\,\hat\theta(x^{(N)}))| < \epsilon
\end{align}
for all $x\in X$.

**Candidate 3.** $p_1$ and $p_2$ are *inference-equivalent* provided they agree when fitted to any amount of data, however large or small.

**Questions.**

Are definitions of this type adopted in the statistics literature?  Are there any interesting, useful theorems proven about equivalent statistical models if so?  Perhaps multiple types of equivalence like the candidates above are discussed in the literature in which case is there discussion of which definitions of equivalence imply one another?

Comment: The problem with candidates 2 and 3 is that they are not well-defined, since they depend on the procedure used to "fit" models.  This approach is ineffective, because one major objective in setting up this mathematical framework is to establish a basis for comparing different estimators. Candidate 1 looks plausible, but a deeper study of the foundations indicates there is more mathematical structure than a mere mapping of sets: large subsets of $\mathscr{P}(X)$ have a natural affine connection or a topology in which the parameterization must be continuous.

Comment: @whuber Yeah I was originally tempted to write something like "asymptotically inference equivalent relative to fitting procedure F" to avoid that issue, but I understand the desire to compare estimators.  Can you suggest a reference whereby your point about the additional mathematical structure is discussed?  Is this resolved in the literature to the extent that a definition that doesn't suffer from the deficiencies you've pointed out is put forward and discussed?

Comment: I believe it is resolved in the literature.  My reference to an affine connection is an allusion to the field of [information geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_geometry).  The standard texts on estimation, such as Lehmann (*Intro to Statistical Inference*), introduce enough mathematics to clarify some of the finer points and also discuss forms of "invariance" in statistical models related to your candidate 1.

Comment: @whuber Much appreciated.

Comment: You appear to have been tempted into reinventing the definitions of _observational equivalence_ (see, for example definition 2 in Rothenberg 1971: http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Identification/Rothenberg_id_Econometrica_71.pdf) and _asymptotic equivalence_ of testing procedures. As pointed out by Ben, these are core ideas in econometric theory.

Comment: @tchakravarty Thanks.  The definitions of those terms do indeed seem similar.  I appreciate the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start by looking at statistical/econometric literature on "[identifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability)".  That concept pertains to reducdancy of parameters in a model, but I suppose it could also accomodate redundancy across model classes (including equivalent models).  There is quite a massive literature on this subject, and many useful theorems have been proven in relation to this concept.

Comment: Any particular place you'd recommend starting?  From what I can gather from the Wikipedia page, it's not obvious that this literature will answer the original question (although it also does look related), so I'd prefer not to fumble around searching for too long if that can be avoided.